# escaping file paths for json (JsonCPP)

Tags: c++, json, escaping, filepath

We're using json format to store configuration data, using JsonCPP for handling the format. A recent extension calls for fields that store some (Windows) file paths. And storing the std::string works - as long as the path doesn't contain anything funny, like spaces, where the path obtains quote marks: `C:\my_directory\data.dat` works fine, but `"C:\my directory\data.dat"` fails, corresponding key becoming `"path"=""C:\my directory\data.dat""` which is invalid json

Escaping is the standard answer, and obviously I could write my own escape/unescape but I shouldn't reinvent the wheel, so I'd like to ask if there is one - what's the standard, simple, lightweight approach (preferably no Boost or something equally heavy)? Some built-in function of JsonCPP, an idiom/snippet using stdlib, a Windows API library call?

What's the "industry standard" approach to escaping file paths for storage in JSON?

VC++; Visual Studio 2015, Win10, MFC.

edit: code.

```
std::string SignalControlDialog::GetDlgItemStdString(UINT id)
{
    TCHAR entry_tchar[1024];
    LPTSTR entry_lptstr = entry_tchar;
    GetDlgItemText(id, entry_lptstr, 1024);
    std::wstring entry_wstring(&entry_tchar[0]);
    std::string entry_string(entry_wstring.begin(), entry_wstring.end());

    return entry_string;
}

//...

  data->project_file = GetDlgItemStdString(IDC_EDIT1);


//...

    Json::Value config;
    Json::StyledStreamWriter writer;

    config["crossingfile"] = data::project_file;

    std::ofstream stream;
    stream.open(GetFileName().c_str());
    if (stream.fail())
        return FALSE;

    writer.write(stream, config);
    stream.close();
```

Comment: In my tests using `JsonCPP` it automatically adds its own escape characters if you put quotes in. What code did you use?

Comment: @Galik: see edit.

Comment: What happens if you just do this? `config["crossingfile"] = R"("C:\my directory\data.dat")";`

Comment: @Galik: will take some time to tell, I don't have the compile environment with me at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, every decent JSON library must do escaping, unescaping itself, it is a core requirement for any serializing library. If JsonCpp does not provide it (did not have any experience with it), then you need consider to switch to something else. Some candidates:

- [Json for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), as the name suggests you have to have at least C++-11 compatible build.
- [Picojson](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson), header-only easy to use library.

I would mention the JSON serializer for Boost Property Tree, but you said no Boost((.